# Marcar selected em option que tem o mesmo id trazido em array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um select `$(".methods option")` que tem 3 options com formas de pagamento e cada option tem um value que tem um ID (no caso 1, 2 e 3 respectivamente). Preciso marcar como selected o option que bater com os IDs trazidos no `data-payment-methods="{{ $timeline->paymentMethods }}"` que nesse exemplo traz 2 objetos com os IDs 2 e 3. No if que fiz no javascript, já está fazendo a verificação e me retornando que os options com IDs 2 e 3 coincidiram com os IDs retornados no array. Preciso agora colocar selected nos options que tem o value 2 e 3.

Console com a variavel `payment` do javascript

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="timeline">

        <article class="timeline-item alt">
            <div class="text-right">
                <div class="time-show">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom w-lg">Histórico</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

        @foreach($timelines as $timeline)
            <article class="timeline-item @if($timeline->user_id == Auth::user()->id) alt @else "" @endif">
                <div class="timeline-desk">
                    <div class="panel m-t-20 m-b-20">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <span class="arrow-alt"></span>
                            <span class="timeline-icon bg-info"><i class="zmdi zmdi-circle"></i></span>
                            <p class="timeline-date text-muted"><small>{{ date( 'd/m/Y H:i' , strtotime($timeline->created_at)) }}</small></p>
                            <p class="m-t-10">Serviço: {{ $order->category->name }}</p>
                            <p class="m-t-10">Status: {{ $timeline->status }}</p>
                            @isset($timeline->price_average)
                                <p class="m-t-10">Valor: R$ {{ number_format($timeline->price_average, 2, ',', '.') }}</p>
                            @endisset
                            @isset($timeline->price_average)
                                @foreach($timeline->paymentMethods as $paymentMethod)
                                    <p class="m-t-10">{{ $paymentMethod['name'] }}</p>
                                @endforeach
                            @endisset
                            <p class="m-t-10">{{ $timeline->description }}</p>
                            <div class="btn-group dropup @if($timeline->user_id == Auth::user()->id) pull-right @else pull-left @endif m-t-10">
                                <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary responder" 
                                    data-category="{{ $order->category->name }}" 
                                    data-price="{{ number_format($timeline->price_average, 2, ',', '.') }}"
                                    data-payment-methods="{{ $timeline->paymentMethods }}" 
                                href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con-close-modal">Responder</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="con-close-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('customer.timelines.store', ['order' => $order, 'supplier' => $supplier]) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title category" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label m-b-10 price" style="text-align: left"></label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="status" name="status">
                                <option value="">Selecione</option>
                                <option value="Aprovado">Aprovado</option>
                                <option value="Contraproposta">Contraproposta</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="price-average-div">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label">Informe um valor em reais para contraproposta:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price-average" name="price_average">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('payment_methods') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <label for="payment_methods">Formas de Pagamento<h6>Selecione as formas de pagamento oferecidas.</h6></label>
                                <select multiple class="form-control methods" name="payment_methods[]" required>
                                    @foreach($paymentMethods as $paymentMethod)
                                        <option value="{{ $paymentMethod->id }}">{{ $paymentMethod->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @if ($errors->has('payment_methods'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('payment_methods') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group no-margin">
                            <label class="control-label m-t-15">Observações:</label>
                            <textarea name="description" class="form-control autogrow" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 104px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light warning-alert-interest">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
$(".responder").click(function(){

    //Select
    var methods = $(".methods option"); //select com options: <option value="{{ $paymentMethod->id }}">{{ $paymentMethod->name }}</option>

    var payment = $(this).data("payment-methods"); //Retorna array de objetos com o value contendo o ID

    $.each(methods, function() {
        var methods = $(this).val();
        console.log(methods); // Retorna 1, 2 e 3
        $.each(payment, function(indexPayment, valuePayment) {
            if (valuePayment.id == methods) {
            console.log("OK: " + valuePayment.id); // Retorna OK: 2 e OK: 3
            //Preciso pegar o option que bateu e colocar selected nele
            }
        });
   });

});
```

Comment: Coloca também seu HTML

Comment: Cara sua pergunta está confusa, no título você quer comparar id no corpo da pergunta você não especifica o que de cada select está comparando, tente editar  pergunta e especificar sua dúvida.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e apresente o html renderizado, isso vai facilitar muito para ajudar a resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insira o código abaixo que verifica se o valor existe no `select` e marca o `option`:

```
//Preciso pegar o option que bateu e colocar selected nele
var val = $('.methods option[value="'+valuePayment.id+'"]');
val.prop('selected', val ? true : false );
```

O código ficaria assim:

```
$(".responder").click(function(){

    //Select
    var methods = $(".methods option"); //select com options: <option value="{{ $paymentMethod->id }}">{{ $paymentMethod->name }}</option>

    var payment = $(this).data("payment-methods"); //Retorna array de objetos com o value contendo o ID

    $.each(methods, function() {
        var methods = $(this).val();
        console.log(methods); // Retorna 1, 2 e 3
        $.each(payment, function(indexPayment, valuePayment) {
            if (valuePayment.id == methods) {
            console.log("OK: " + valuePayment.id); // Retorna OK: 2 e OK: 3
            //Preciso pegar o option que bateu e colocar selected nele
               var val = $('.methods option[value="'+valuePayment.id+'"]');
               val.prop('selected', val ? true : false );
            }
        });
   });

});
```

Comment: Editei a pergunta porque estava meio confusa, porque na verdade é somente um select.

Comment: @Marcelo Atualizei a resposta. Veja se era isto. Vc quer pegar os valores de uma array?

Comment: Esse if (valuePayment.id == methods), a variável valuePayment.id ja me traz os IDs do array que no caso é 2 e 3. O methods me traz os values do select que no caso é 1, 2 e 3. Preciso agora colocar selected no segundo e terceiro options.

Comment: @Marcelo Pelo que entendi, era só alterar o valor que coloquei no meu código. Veja na resposta atualizada agora.

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Bom eu considero mais simples uma resposta direta ao título da pergunta em sí. Assim gerando um código mais sucinto, se atendo ao objetivo principal, que funcionaria desta forma abaixo:

```js
var sel = 'select.methods',
    ary = $(sel).attr('data-payment-methods').split(',');

ary.forEach(function(x){ $(sel+' option').eq(x-1).attr('selected', ''); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-payment-methods=1,2,3 multiple class="form-control methods" name="payment_methods[]" required>
<!-- alterar 1,2,3 para o valor que for retornar do php para testes -->
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Você pode alterar o valor do atributo `data-payment-methods` que encontra-se em `1,2,3` para quaisquer você quiser para intuitos de teste, uma vez que o valor deste, será gerado, na verdade, pelo [php](/questions/tagged/php).